# SSRS format 8.840 to 8.83

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am working on the Report I would like to display the decimal number from  8.84079343397399 to 8.83

Here is my sql query

```
select  (4.83+1.923*LOG10(CAST(c.catchGirth as float))+1.157*LOG10(CAST(c.catchLength as float)))
         as  estimatesWeight  
 from Catches c 
 where c.id =@CatchId
```

The result is 8.84079343397399
I want the result from 8.84079343397399 to 8.83 or if result  8.84579343397399 to 8.84

Comment: " I want the result from 8.84079343397399 to 8.83" - makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS offers the following methods to perform rounding:

- **Ceiling** - Rounds a decimal number up to next whole number (8.84 becomes 9, 8.1 also becomes 9)
- **Floor** - Rounds a decimal number down to whole number (8.84 becomes 8)
- **Round** - At the desired precision, rounds number up if number to right is 5-9 or down if number of right is 0-4 (so Round(8.8402,2) rounds to 8.84, and Round(8.845, 2) rounds to 8.85

**Edit**
Based on your edit, Round does not offer a Floor at a precision, but assuming the value was in a value called `Value`, then `CDbl(Floor(Value * 100)) / 100`.